# Highest jumper out of 3

Tags: probability

Let $X_j$ be how high the $j{th}$ jumper jumped, with $X_1$, $X_2$,... i.i.d. with a continuous distribution.
We say that the $j^{th}$ jumper is “best in recent memory” if they jump higher than
the previous 2 jumpers (for j = 3; the first 2 jumpers don’t qualify).

Let $A_j$ be the event that the $j^{th}$ jumper is the best in recent memory. Find $P(A_3 \cap
A_4)$, $P(A_3)$, and $P(A_4)$. Are $A_3$ and $A_4$ independent?

My take on it is a s follows:

$P(A_4) = P(A_3) = \frac{1}{3}$ by symmetry.

$P(A_4 \cap A_3) = P(A_4|A_3)P(A_3) = \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$ - This because if $3^{rd}$ jumper is best of 3, $4^{th}$ jumper is better than the $3^{rd}$ half of the time.

However this can be also considered in the following way:

- all orderings of the 4 jumpers are equally likely
- 2 out of the $4!$ orders satisfy $A_4 \cap A_3$ - 4,3,2,1 and 4,3,1,2

Based on this $P(A_3 \cap A_4) = \frac{2}{4!} = \frac{1}{12}$

The results are different which means I make a mistake somewhere. I'd appreciate some thoughts on it.

Comment: I don't believe the assertion "if $3^{rd}$ jumper is best of 3, $4^{th}$ jumper is better than the $3^{rd}$ half of the time". If you are the last of four people in a jumping context, do you believe that you'd have the same odds of winning against the _best_ of the other three that you would against a _randomly chosen_ person from the other three?

Comment: At the end you change from $A_3,A_4$ to $A,B$

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true that if the $3^{rd}$ jumper is the best of the first three, the fourth will beat it half the time.  We know the third is either the best of the four or second, but we have no information about the fourth, so the third will beat the fourth more than half the time.  Your count at the end is the correct approach, but if $1$ is the best jumper the two orders that satisfy $A_3 \cap A_4$ are $3,4,2,1$ and $4,3,2,1$.  As you say, $P(A_3)=\frac 13$, so $$P(A_4|A_3)=\frac{P(A_3 \cap A_4)}{P(A_3)}=\dfrac{\frac 1{12}}{\frac 13}=\frac 14$$

Comment: Yes, this makes sense, thank you. I made a mistake considering the $4^{th}$ jumper higher than what $3^{rd}$ was higher than, which is incorrect.